# How to access Parent scope of My current Parent from ModalForm in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a parent controller `User`, inside `User` controller, I wrote a method to get userDetails

```
export default class UserController {

  constructor(userService) {
     this._userService = userService;
  }
  getUserDetails(){
    return this._userService.getDetails()
  }
}
```

Also I have a child controller `Home` for `UserController`.  Inside the Home page, I have added a Modal Form,

```
export default class HomeController {

  constructor() {

  }
    showUploadDialog(ev) {
      this._mdDialog.show({
      templateUrl: './modules/upload-properties/uploadproperties.tpl.html',
      locals: { home: this },
      controller: 'UploadPropertiesController',
      controllerAs: 'uploader',
      bindToController: true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true
    });
  }
}
```

My Modal form controller is this

```
 export default class UploadPropertiesController{

          constructor() {

          }

          getUserDetailsFromParent(){   //I need to get user details from Parent UserController
            return user.getUserDetails()
          }
        }
```

How can I access Parent (UserController) `$scope` of my current parent from ModalForm

Comment: You don't need to access parent scope. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I think modal form have isolated scope . so If I want to access 'UserController's (Parent of  current Parent) method from Modal Form page, How its possible?

Comment: The scope is isolated, but you can access it, of course. But once again: this is bad approach, that's why you should not do it. What method, what does it do/return why modal needs it? There is proper solution.

Comment: Anyway, documentation has clear description how to do it easily (show method options).

Comment: I need to display user details in my modal form. I have added 'getUserDetails()'  in My parent Controller, so that I can reuse it every where. Will you please give any documentation link

Comment: @Anuraj You should use a service/factory. The service should have the `getUserDetails` method. Inject that into both the parent controller & the modal form so that the both can use it.